# Javascript if else conditionals not returning the desired output

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I've been teaching myself how to code in new languages and might be asking a couple of silly questions here for a while.

Trying to put this to work but, when the output pops out and the grade I've typed into is higher than 50, it was supposed to show the word "PASS". Instead, I'm still getting "FAIL"  - the amount doesn't matter.

I am pretty sure it has to do with the conditionals, but I've been stuck on this for a long time now.

Here is my code:

```
var input = Number(prompt("Enter a grade between 0 and 100.")); //enter grade

if (input > 100 || input < 0) {
    alert("Grade not valid. Enter a grade between 0 and 100."); //validate grade
} else {
    if (input < 50); //result FAIL
    {
        result = "Fail";
        alert("FAIL");
    }

    /*
        if (input > 50); //result PASS - This part doesn't work
        {
        result = "Pass";
        alert("PASS");
        }
    */

    total = total + input;
    entrys = entrys + 1; //show inputed grades
    document.write("<br>" + "Grade " + entrys + " = " + input + " = " + input / 100 + "%" + "  " + result); // Every inputed result is considered "Fail"
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `;` after the `if` conditions.

Comment: Thanks!! All good now!

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after the `if (input < 50)` turns the if statement into a one line if with an empty expression, followed by a code block that always runs. You can fix your issue by getting rid of the semicolon.

```js
if (input < 50); //result FAIL
//             ^ this is bad
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you need to remove the `;` from the line if you want the rest of the statements to execute. The reason why is because, traditionally, in compiler languages the semicolon(`;`) is used to mark the end of the line. In javascript, they are also used for that purpose, but they are **optional** in javascript.

So if your code spans multiple lines, avoid using it unnecessarily. Definitely don't use it after a `for` or `while` loop(unless for certain use cases where you want that), or after an `if-else` statement, because execution will get stopped at that line and the next line will be executed like it is an unrelated code and not part of the loop/statement. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Thanks!!! Learned a lesson for life. All good now!